# how to check product has custom options?

Tags: magento-1.8, custom-options

I'm Trying to check whether product has custom options or not in code (my code runs `sales_order_place_after` event). 
I have try below code but it does not returning anything.
`$product->hasCustomOptions()`
and
`$product->hasOptions()`

Please let me know what i'm missing

Comment: @Marius You have answered similar question at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745879/product-has-a-custom-options-or-not-in-magento So may be you can help me

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the $product model correctly? Maybe you should show more of your code in context?